# PHP and download pdf file from local server

Tags: php, pdf, curl, server, local

I have a problem with download pdf from local server. I have an url to a document file (example: \10.10.10.10\directory\123_ABC.pdf). I must make php function which download file from url and show it in web browser. Access to this directory is protected (username and password). I don't know how I can download this file. Maybe curl? This is possible?

I tried this:

```
$login = 'LOGIN';
$password = 'PASSOWRD';
$host = "http://10.10.10.10/directory/123_ABC.pdf";
$CurlConnect = curl_init();
curl_setopt($CurlConnect, CURLOPT_URL, $host);
curl_setopt($CurlConnect, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
curl_setopt($CurlConnect, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $login.':'.$password);
$Result = curl_exec($CurlConnect);

header('Cache-Control: public');
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="new.pdf"');
header('Content-Length: '.strlen($Result));
v($Result) ;
```

The file new.pdf is displayed in the browser, but it is broken.

EDIT:
I resolved problem. I couldn't download pdf file because I used bad protocol.
This code is correct:

```
$login = 'LOGIN';
$password = 'PASSOWRD';
$host = "ftp://10.10.10.10/directory/123_ABC.pdf";
$CurlConnect = curl_init();
curl_setopt($CurlConnect, CURLOPT_URL, $host);
curl_setopt($CurlConnect, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
curl_setopt($CurlConnect, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $login.':'.$password);
$Result = curl_exec($CurlConnect);
curl_close ($ch);
header('Cache-Control: public');
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="new.pdf"');
header('Content-Length: '.strlen($Result));
echo $Result;
```

Comment: What method is used to password protect this file? HTTP Authentication?

Comment: Set Header Data to application/pdf and use echo file_get_contents(); and die();

Answer (score 0):

You can use [file_put_contents](http://php.net/file_put_contents) to download the file from url to your server.

```
file_put_contents("example.pdf", fopen("http://10.10.10.10\directory\123_ABC.pdf","rb"));
```

Comment: the fopen is just a waste, provided that `allow_url_fopen` is on, file_put_contents fetches http urls just as well as fopen, but if it's disabled, neither of them will work. and how to download it with a username and password depends on the authentication method used, but in all cases, this is the wrong approach, you don't provide username/password anywhere in this snippet

Comment: @hanshenrik the fopen opens the url with the attributes and file_put_contents will stream the opened file. Yeah the conditions will be both should be kept open.

Answer (score 0):

Quote: `The file new.pdf is displayed in the browser, but it is broken` - that is incorrect, the pdf file is not displayed in the browser, but because you sent the header `header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="new.pdf"');` , telling the browser that you're sending it a pdf file, the browser try to render your logged out error page as a pdf, and because HTML (which your logged out error page probably consists of) and PDF are 2 completely different formats, the pdf parser can't render it (most drastic difference is that HTML is text based, and PDF is a binary format)

how to log in depends on what login system the server use. curl has built-in support for a few types, namely `HTTP Basic authentication` and `HTTP Digest authentication` and `HTTP NTLM authentication`, most of which are standardized, but **none of which are widely used.** most likely, they use a custom login scheme which you'll have to implement yourself. the most common scheme includes sending the username and password to a login page, then the login page provides a `session id` in a cookie, and you must use that cookie to access all pages that needs you to be logged in. (for example, stackoverflow.com , wikipedia.com , and facebook.com all have their own version of this cookie-session-id scheme) - you'll have to find out what login scheme the server use, before anyone here can tell you how to log in. if you're lucky though, they use 1 of the (rare) schemes built-in to curl, in which case you'll have to use CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH together with  CURLOPT_USERPWD to log in.. the method used for logging in is best deduced by studying the login page. what http headers and body do you get when going to the login page in your browser? in Google Chrome, you can see this by pressing Ctrl+Shift+I, then going to the "Network" tab before browsing to the login page, then browse to the page, then you should see the request in the Network tab, there you can see the received and sent headers and the response body (usually html)